# Read from textfile and store into an array (JAVA)

Tags: java

```
public static Student[] getInput(Scanner scanner)throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //change the array size by reading the input file
    Student[] classList=new Student[10];
    int i;
    int numberOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();

    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {   
        while(numberOfStudents > classList.length)
        {
            //enlargeList(classList[i]);
        }

        for(i = 0; i <= classList.length; i++){
            String studentId = scanner.nextLine();
            int mark = scanner.nextInt();
            classList[i] = new Student(studentId, mark);
        }   
    }
    return classList;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (args.length!=1)
    {
        System.out.println("Usage GradeManager inputFileName");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Scanner inFile=null;
    try{
        //do the whole try block in the lab
        String fileName = args[0];
        //Open a file with FileName and creaste a scanner using it
        inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        Student[] classList=getInput(inFile);

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fe)
    {
        fe.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(inFile!=null)
            inFile.close();
    }
}
```

So I am trying read from a textfile that is as follows:

```
9

V0012345 98

V0023456 33

V0024615 51

V0089546 57

V0015348 61

V0054162 69

V0044532 87

V0031597 74

V0074615 78
```

First line is the number of students in the text file, all others are student number + their grade in the class. I'm trying to import these into the array classList[]. I am very new to java and object oriented stuff, so I'm sorry in advance if my code is garbage. I have omitted the enlargeList method as it works and I've tested it.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the error.  Is it a compiler error message?  An exception stack trace?  Wrong output?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String studentId = scanner.nextLine();
```

will read `V0012345 98` and then

```
int mark = scanner.nextInt();
```

will read `V0023456 33` and fail

try:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();

//this will ignore empty lines
if(line.equals("")) continue;

String[] lineArray = line.split(" ");
String studentId = lineArray[0];
int mark = Integer.parseInt(lineArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least four problems I can see...

First, `int numberOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();` won't consume the new line character, this means the next time you try and read something from the scanner, you may get the new line character (if you're reading text) or an exception of you're reading a numeric value.

Try adding `scanner.nextLine()` after it, for example...

```
int numberOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();
```

You're pre-initializing the array before you know the number of possible lines.  This seems weird to me.  You know ahead of time how many lines you will need to read, why not use it?

```
int numberOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();
Student[] classList = new Student[numberOfStudents];
```

Next, when reading the student data, you seem to be reading the entire line, the looking for an `int` value after it...

This would mean you are reading `V0012345 98` using `scanner.nextLine()`, but the next call to `scanner.nextInt()` will encounter `V0023456`, which isn't a valid `int` value.

Instead, read the next line and create a new `Scanner` to parse it...

```
Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(line);
String studentId = scanLine.next();
int mark = scanLine.nextInt();
```

This is just one possible means for doing this, but I wanted to stick with the `Scanner` usage simply because you seem comfortable with it...

Now, somewhere in your compound loops, something gets messed up and the `Scanner` is getting out of sync.

Now, because we've initialised our array to the header information we read first, we can remove the compound loop in favor of something like...

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine() && classList.length < i) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(line);
    String studentId = scanLine.next();
    int mark = scanLine.nextInt();
    scanLine.close();
    classList[i] = new Student(studentId, mark);
    i++;
}
```

Instead.  I've left the array length check in just in case the file is lying.  This means that the header can report just about any value it wants, but the loop will check for the availability of data in the file AND that we have room to read it...

This all assumes that there are no blank lines in the file you are trying to read, unlike the example you posted.  If there is, you would need to add a check in and skip those lines

Comment: Theres a function we need to write in here called grow array, as we will be also adding students through the command line (But not saving that info to the text file). So we really don't know what the array is.

Comment: Focus on the initial part, reading the file.  Once you have the file, you can then grow the array later.  You could change the `while-loop` to only check `scanner.hasNextLine()` and make determinations about whether you need to grow the array before you add the next `Student` to it...